# AngularJS count matching occurrences in an array

Tags: arrays, angularjs

Objective:  I want to count the occurrences of an id matching between arrays
The code below finds the match but we need to count the result

```
    var arr1 =  [ 

     {
    "image" : "FF815_1.jpg",
    "id" : "NO"
  }, {
    "image" : "FF815_0.jpg",
    "id" : "NO"
  }, {
    "image" : "FF815_4.jpg",
    "id" : "NO"
  }, {
    "image" : "PIOJD_2.jpg",
   "id" : "NO"
  }, {
    "image" : "PIOJD_4.jpg",
    "id": "JD"
  } ];
  
var arr2 =  [ 

     {
    "image" : "FF815_1.jpg",
    "id" : "NO"
  }, {
    "image" : "FF815_0.jpg",
    "id" : "NO"
  }, {
    "image" : "FF815_4.jpg",
    "id" : "NO"
  }, {
    "image" : "PIOJD_2.jpg",
    "id" : "JD"
  }, {
    "image" : "PIOJD_4.jpg",
    "id" : "JD"
  } ];


 angular.forEach(arr1, function(value1, key1) {
        angular.forEach(arr2, function(value2, key2) {
            if (value1.id === value2.id) {
            console.log(value2.id);
    }
    });
  });
```

Heres a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/62s0ae7v/

Comment: Ideas:  create a new array and pass results to new array and count .length

Answer (score 1):

Just add a simple counter like :

```
var counter = 0;
angular.forEach(arr1, function(value1, key1) {
    angular.forEach(arr2, function(value2, key2) {
        if (value1.image === value2.image) {
            console.log(value2.image);
            counter++;
        }
    });
});
console.log(counter);
```